# Vim: Is it possible to open a new line for editing directly below the cursor position?

Tags: vim

Is there a Vim command that opens a new line below the current line but at also the same column as the current cursor position in the line above it?

Comment: Open above/below is the closest you'll get. For future ref: http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could try something like this:

```
:nnoremap <S-CR> :put =repeat(' ', virtcol('.') - 1)<Bar>retab!<Bar>startinsert!<CR>
```